# $.ajax get error just when call it from phone

Tags: android, jquery, ajax

$.ajax get error just when call it from phone

hi every body , i have a ajax code and it is dont work when i open this page from mobile ( galaxy s2 ) , then i just write a simple ajax code

```
 $.ajax( "my url" )
        .done(function() {
            alert( "success" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
             alert( "error" );
        });
```

it is work good when i open this page with laptop or tablet(android) but when i open it from my phone , i get error alert , what is the problem , i have no idea

Comment: it is have no error , i use all ways that can show ajax error , all them show nothing

Answer (score 0):

i get answer , for two days i work on it 
you link must be in your domain and not start by domain

www.site.com/method = false 
/method = true